# plot two y axis graph with na values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

```
data <- data.frame( Timestamp =c("2011-05-03 00:00:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:01:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:02:00 UTC",
 "2011-05-03 00:03:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:04:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:05:00 UTC",
  "2011-05-03 00:06:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:07:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:08:00 UTC",      "2011-05-03 00:09:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:10:00 UTC" ,"2011-05-03 00:11:00 UTC",
 "2011-05-03 00:12:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:13:00 UTC" ,"2011-05-03 00:14:00 UTC",
 "2011-05-03 00:15:00 UTC" ,"2011-05-03 00:16:00 UTC" ,"2011-05-03 00:17:00 UTC",
 "2011-05-03 00:18:00 UTC", "2011-05-03 00:19:00 UTC"  ), v1 =c(1:8,NA,20:25,NA,17:20), v2=c(1:4,NA,16:21,NA,23:28,NA,20),v3=c(1:10,21:30))
```

I have a data Frame like the above. I would like to plot "Timestamp vs v1, v2, v2" in a single plot. How can I plot line graph with this data.?

Comment: The first thing you could do is improve your question and provide a http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruth,

If I understand correct you want something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  gather(Vgroup, value, -Timestamp) %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 

ggplot(aes(Timestamp, value, colour=Vgroup)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I wanted..  can i explain how this works because I'm new to R

Comment: @Ruth there are two main components when solving this problem: data munging, for which we used dplyr and plotting, where we took advantage of the ggplot package. I suggest that you get started with this -excellent- book: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/ and let me know what questions you have on it. Good luck!